# Delay between UIActivityIndicatorView animation stop and content view refresh

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, progress-bar, delay

I have created a simple `UIActivityIndicatorView` that takes care of informing the user about the end of the execution for a specific task. My implementation is the following:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
spinner.center = self.imageView.center;
[self.imageView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    UIImage *filteredImage = ...some filtering...;
    self.imageView.image = filteredImage;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [spinner stopAnimating];
    });

});
```

However, when I run the application, the spinning wheel disappears and after a while the image is updated. Do you have any hint about how there is this delay?

EDIT: the `setNeedsDisplay` and the `stopAnimating` instructions are called in the right order. However, the `UIImageView` takes a while in order to update its content.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can put log on above of both stopAnimating line and setNeedsDisplay line so you can have better idea which is logged first.

Comment: The order is correct: the `setNeedsDisplay` function is called before the animation stop. However, the image takes a while for being updated.

Comment: have no idea but have 1 suggestion if you want to forcefully achieve your desired output then you can call a method with delay and stop your activity indicator into that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is-
You are trying to assigning image on imageview on other thread instead of main thread (GUI thread) so it takes time.

To resolve this I have made few changes in your code-

Instead of using this-

```
    UIImage *filteredImage = ...some filtering...;
    self.imageView.image = filteredImage;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Try this-

```
self.imageView.image = filteredImage;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.imageView.image = filteredImage;
        [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    });
```

I have also faced this, hope it helps you.